# normality test for a set of vectors in python (numpy/scipy etc)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, normal-distribution

I have a 2D numpy array A (m*n) where each row contain a random vector of size n. I would like to check if these m vectors are normally distributed.

I saw the function scipy.stats.normaltest but it seems this function can only deal with real numbers (not sure). Is there an existed function to test the normality of a set of real vectors?